# Is there a way to style the password discs in an input?

Tags: html, css, input, passwords

In HTML/CSS, is there a way to change the color/size of password inputs?

Comment: I don't think that that is possible because that kind of thing is generally managed by the browser. Your best bet is probably to use some kind of js library. Haven't done any research so I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```html
<input style="color:red;width:100px;height:50px;"type="password" value="1234567890">
```

If you want the password input to be more fancy:

```css
input,
.filter-blur {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

input:focus,
.filter-blur-focused {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: rgb(94, 158, 214);
}

.filter-blur input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-blur"><input value="password123" /></div>
```